# Norm of $l_g : C^0[0,1] \to \mathbb{K}$ is $|| l_g || = \int_{0}^{1} |g(t)| dt$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Show that for every $g \in C^0[0,1]$ a continuous functional $l_g :C^0[0,1] \to \mathbb{K}$ with $f \mapsto \int_{0}^{1} f(t)g(t) dt$ is defined by, for which $|| l_g || = \int_{0}^{1} |g(t)| dt$

Goor day, I have to show that $||l_g||$ is the norm of that linear continuous transformation, where this is $L(E,F) $= $\{A : E \to F $| A is linear and continuous } 
My professor give us a Hint:

Suppose $f$ is integrable on the circle and $f$ is bounded by
$B$. Then there exists a sequence $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of continuous functions on the circle so that
$sup_{x \in [-\pi,\pi]} |f_k(x)| < B$ for all $k = 1, 2, ...$,
and
 $ \int_{-\pi}^{pi} |f(x)-f_k(x)| dx \to 0 $ as $k \to 1$

But I don't really see the relations of this result with the exercise. Thank you if you can help me.

Pdta: $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C} $

Comment: It is almost trivial to show that $|l_g(f)|\le\|f\|_\infty\int_0^1|g(t)|\,dt$. Then this implies that $l_g$ is bounded with norm $\|l_g\|\le\int_0^1|g(t)|\,dt$. Now, it remains to prove equality.

Comment: I understand your point, but I don't understand why the relation with that result.

Comment: And we don't use the infinity norm.

Comment: $\|\cdot\|_{L^{\infty}}=\sup(\cdot)$ for continuous functions.

Comment: "And we don't use the infinity norm." Yes, you do! When you write $C[a,b]$, then you mean $(C[a,b],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ if not otherwise stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, it is clear that $\|l_g\|\le\int_0^1|g(t)|\,dt$. If $|g|>0$ on $[0,1]$, then with $f = \overline{g}/|g|$ we have $\|f\|_\infty=1$ and $fg = |g|$, so $l_g(f) = \int_0^1|g(t)|\,dt$, and we are done. In the case where $g$ has zeros, we set
$$
f_n := \frac{\|g\|_\infty+\frac 1n}{\|g\|_\infty}\cdot\frac{\overline{g}}{|g|+\frac 1n}.
$$
Then $\|f_n\|_\infty=1$ for each $n$ and $f_ng = |f_n||g|$, which converges pointwise to $|g|$ (also at zeros of $g$). This gives $l_g(f_n) = \int_0^1|f_n(t)||g(t)|\,dt\to \int_0^1|g(t)|\,dt$ by dominated convergence, which proves the claim.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how the tip helps neither, but the following is another approach if you just look for any proof.

Extend $g(x)=0$ for $x\notin[0,1]$ and consider the standard mollifier $\varphi_{\epsilon}\ast\text{sgn}(g)\in C(\mathbb{R})$, then $l_{g}(\varphi_{\epsilon}\ast\text{sgn}(g))\rightarrow\|g\|_{L^{1}}$ and $\|\varphi_{\epsilon}\ast\text{sgn}(g)\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq\|\varphi_{\epsilon}\|_{L^{1}}\|\text{sgn}(g)\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq 1$. So $\|l_{g}\|\geq\|g\|_{L^{1}}$.